# Change background image using data binding

Tags: java, android

In gradle I enabled data binding. After attempting to change the background image, when i run the app, I observed the following errors in the logs:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. ImageBacground is missing it
file:D:\Bogv\Android project\Pote\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment1.xml
loc:13:19 - 13:32
****\ data binding error ****
```

**My view class:**

```
    public class ImageBacground {
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ImageBacground(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;

    }
   @BindingAdapter({"android:src"})
    public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String imageUrl) {
        Picasso.with(view.getContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.potehki_fon)
                .into(view);
    }

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }

    public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }
}
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable name="images" type="com.retrofa.potehkilulibalse.images.ImageBacground"/>
    </data>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/first_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:src="@{ImageBacground.loadImage,default=@drawable/potehki_fon}"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

    >

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/eda" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/umivanie" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/son" />
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: There two ways to do it  1) By using data binding you can find your imageView's Id in your java code and you can set imageUrl using picasso.

Comment: Another way is that you forgot to bind imageUrl in your xml code. First bind that imageUrl to ImageView Widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your custom binding Adapter

```
 public class CustomBinding {

   @BindingAdapter({"imageUrl"})
   public static void loadImage(LinearLayout layout, Drawable drawable) {
       if (drawable != null) {
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
               layout.setBackground(drawable);
           } else {
               layout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Then in xml you can use like this

**activity_main.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
     <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       app:imageUrl="@{@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp}">
    </LinearLayout>
 </layout>
```

Now, bind xml layout in `onCreate()` method of activity file

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: i want set background into LinearLayout not ImageView

Comment: and i should to add <data> tag?

Comment: No. And let me know if no working. I have not tested this code in Android Studio. I directly written answer here,.

Comment: @ Kishan Vaghela
Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'imageUrl' in package

Comment: it is *app:imageUrl* or *android:imageUrl*

Comment: @upwardunkaind I have edited answer. Now it is tested ok, and works for me. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139167/discussion-between-kishan-vaghela-and-upward-unkaind).